# Sharing files between a containerized CLI and the host

Tags: docker, containers, command-line-interface

I need to containerize an existing CLI that also reads and writes files. Something similar to a containerized`cp` or `kubectl` any other typical bash command.

Is there a way to wrap the docker command to enable access to files on the host system?

`cat my_wrapper.sh`:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

docker run --rm -it -v ??? \
    $IMAGE \
    "$@"
```

Is there a way to mount anything such that `my_wrapper.sh` can read and write files, as in `my_wrapper.sh --option /some/file/argument`  ?

**Clarification**

Of course, you can simply mount the path the file is located, but then:

1. How can I keep the arguments working correctly? Especially absolute paths.
2. How to avoid parsing the command line for file-like names?

Comment: As an isolation system, Docker _by design_ separates the container and host filesystems, plus it's more oriented towards server-type programs and generally requires root permissions to do anything.  I wouldn't try to run simple CLI programs in Docker -- compare the script you've already written to the single-word commands you offer as examples.

Comment: @DavidMaze right, I'm encapsulating a complex system into containers. Unfortunately, this complex system also comes with it's own CLI

Comment: That doesn't mean the CLI has to run in a container.  You mention `kubectl` and that's a good example: most of Kubernetes runs inside containers, but the CLI tool itself is generally run as a non-container standalone tool.

Comment: @DavidMaze Right. If we don't find a solution here, installing this on the hosts is the backup plan. I'd upvote that, if you want to convert it into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed you can do it with a [bindmount volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/):

`$ my_wrapper.sh /some/file/argument`

Content of my_wrapper.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]; then
    echo "Illegal number of parameters"
    exit 1
else
    if [ -f "$1" ]; then
        dir=$(dirname "$1")
    else
        echo "File doesn't exist"
        exit 2
    fi
fi

IMAGE=xxxx

docker run --rm -it -v "$dir":"$dir" \
    "$IMAGE" \
    "$1"
```

Comment: that's the trivial answer by magically deducing the directory to be `/some/file/` but that only works for this example. I'll clarify the qustion

Comment: You want to dynamically set the bindmount volume depending on the location of the file you're passing as an argument to your wrapper?